# Overwritte Childs Property with CSS

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` element inside a `<li>` element (as shown in code snippet). The `<li>` element has `cursor: pointer` style property set and I can't remove the cursor pointer in that nested `<div>` element.

The `<li>` is not in our control to remove `css`, since it comes from a third party.

```css
.container {
  cursor: pointer
}

.local {
  cursor: default !important
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="container">
    <div class="local"> Hello World </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.container` class is actually irrelevant here. It just so happens that it has a `cursor: pointer` property which shows on, but the problem is in fact - What is overriding the `.local` classed `<div>` element from rendering the `cursor: default` property.

The best way to answer that would be to take a look at the elements and styles panels on your browsers developer tools and see what's doing that. It will let you know what's overriding it.

Then you can use adjustments, either by increasing specificity, or by changing the code that's overriding it. But the specificity needs to be relevant in comparison with the `.local` class  and whatever is actually overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* In the provided example, you don't need to worry about specificity because they're different classes. However, I frequently see `!important` being added to rules as a lazy way to override specificity issues that aren't replicated in the example. I assume that to be the case here as well since the OP notes that, "the container comes from a third party". So understanding specificity rules will help resolve the issue.

---

You *could* use `!important` but that should really be a last resort. However, you're much better served long term by increasing [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Currently `.container` & `.local` have equal weight. You can increase specificity by: Using an ID, referencing more hierarchy, using combinators etc. Then the NEW attributes will override the previous attributes based on CSS order.

Eg:

```
.element {
  background: blue;
}
.element {
  background: red;
}
// produces a red element
```

So in this case you want to increase specificity. You can do that easily like this:

```
.container {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.container > .local {
 cursor: default;
}
// where local is a DIRECT child of .container
```

Comment: Specificity is irrelevant here. The subjects of the two selectors are different.

Comment: Yeah the question might be a bit confusing but in fact the `.container` class is irrelevant. The question is what is actually blocking the `cursor:default` property on the `.local` class.

Comment: let me try above solution

Comment: weird, the same code above works now without parent to child css class like

Comment: @kobe sometimes the easiest way to solve a problem is to do the same thing over again and again until the magic actually works :-)